# extjs 4.2.1 - Radiogroup: add a radio button with a textbox

Tags: javascript, html, css, extjs, extjs4.2

In my UI, I have a single-select RadioGroup with a few options to choose from.  One of the options will contain a textfield that the user can enter input into like this:

```
() Option A
() Option B
() Other (Please specify) ____
```

How would I add something like this to a RadioGroup?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For creating layout of "Other" option you can use [`container`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.container.Container) component with [`hbox`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.layout.container.HBox) layout. This component will have two items. First item will be [`radio`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Radio) and the second item will be [`textfield`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Text).

For creating space between `radio` and `textfield` components you can use [`splitter`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.resizer.Splitter).

```
{
    xtype: 'radiogroup',
    fieldLabel: 'Choose',
    columns: 1,
    vertical: true,
    items: [
        { boxLabel: 'Option 1', name: 'rb', inputValue: '1' },
        { boxLabel: 'Option 2', name: 'rb', inputValue: '2' },
        {
            xtype: 'container',
            layout: 'hbox',
            items: [
                { 
                    xtype: 'radio',
                    boxLabel: 'Other (Please specify)', 
                    name: 'rb', 
                    inputValue: '3' 
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'splitter'
                },                            
                {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    name: 'option3detail'

                }
            ]
        }              
    ]
}
```

Fiddle with live example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/2kj

Comment: Doing like this, you will have troubles when setting the value of the radiogroup because its setValue method expects that its children are all radiofields. So you will have to override the radiogroup setValue method to suit your needs.